# How to make a selection of a datatable into a new smaller datatable within a loop

Tags: vb.net, select, datatable

See the picture for extra info.

I have a datatable with unique adresses. dtUniqueAdresses
I have another datatable with all sort of adresses and some additional columns
dtAdresses

Then i want to create a loop with the following goal in the loop...
For each unique adress select this adress from dtAdresseswhich generates a set of matching rows with the same adresses as the selected unique adress.
Make a new datatable or dataview from this set of matching adressrows and call it dtSelectedAdresses.
Then on this new datatable (or dataview>) dtSelectedAdresses i do some excercise like finding the highest value- of NUMBER for example.
And when ready i pick the next uniqueadress, make the selection and find teh highest value and so on.
The problem i have now is that i have working code of similar problems but they were never in a loop. I tried with datarows new datatables inside and outside the loop and dataviews but all generate different errors. Somehow code examples from the internet cant be used in a loop succesfully. Any idea whats the best way to get a changing datatable within a loop?

[image]

Here some bad codes i tried, i tried more but it gives you an idea that i am a beginner although my total software is working fine...

[image]

Comment: Do not post code as an image. Copy and paste into your question and then format as code.

Comment: I assume the data for this is coming from a database. What was the select string to produce dtUniqueAdresses.